# Can a Bundle ID be reused for a different app within the same iTunes Connect account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

My client is planning to release an iOS app (call it A) on the App Store which only has value for a limited time (say, a few weeks). After that time, they want to release another, basically completely different app (call it B), with functionality that is related to app A, but much more general. B will be built from scratch and will reuse no code at all from A.

They want to release B as an update to A, so as to retain their user base. Technically this should be no problem: we can change name/icon/metadata, as long as we keep the Bundle ID the same. But will this be a problem with the review process? Could Apple decide that it would be confusing for the user to release a completely different app as an update to an existing one?

So a different way of putting my question would be: can we freely reuse a Bundle ID for a different app within the same account?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is absolutely acceptable. I don't see any reason why Apple would reject your app.

*I personally recently updated an app with a new icon and a new name.*

Granted, I kept most of the features from the previous version, but I really don't see Apple rejecting an update based on "it's too different from the previous version". Also, you often see notes in updates saying "rewritten from scratch", so this is also perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can do this, and lack of code re-use is irrelevant.

I have written and submitted apps that have have had their codebase completely replaced over their lifetime.

I've also changed an app's icons and name, so all the component parts are definitely OK to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse a bundle ID. Your best option is to just update the app. The review process accounts for major changes like this, so it will most likely be a longer review time.